# Как рассчитать кол-во дней до след года?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне рассчитать кол-во оставшихся дней до след года? Никак не могу понять, что на что умножать или делить..)

Comment: А как бы решал это с карандашом и листком бумаги?

Comment: Мне нужно сложить все дни прошедших месяцев и отнять их от кол-ва дней в году.. Но я не особо понимаю, как мне сложить эти дни

Comment: Вот зачем? составь дату 1 января следующего года, да посчитай разность в днях.

Comment: new Date(2021, 0, 1) это дата 1 января 2021, а как мне теперь найти кол-во оставшихся дней? Мне нужно динамически выводить их на страницу

Comment: Пробовал умножать getMonth() на getDate().... Нет слов, так чтобы не обидеть

Comment: @IvaMuxa, программирование раньше: сложные алгоритмы, эвристические битовые хаки. Программирование сегодня: буду рандомно умножать одно на другое, пока не получу нужный результат.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov токсичные вы)

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров, к чему эти ярлыки за безобидную шутку, которая просто отражает реальность?

Comment: я просто попросил помощи, вместо безобидных шуток можно было бы просто дать подсказку) а умножал я потому что было интересно, что получится.. вот и всё)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const currentDate = new Date;
const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
console.log("Нынешний год: ", currentYear);

const nextYear = currentYear + 1;
const nextYearDate = new Date( nextYear, 0, 1);
console.log('Полночь, Новый Год: ', nextYearDate);

const diff = nextYearDate - currentDate;

console.log('Разница между годами в миллисекундах: ', diff);

const second = 1000;
const minute = second * 60;
const hour = minute * 60;
const day = hour * 24;

// Можно округлить вниз с помощью Math.floor
console.log('Разница между годами в днях: ', diff / day);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Целых дней до нг

```js
const getNextYearTime=()=>{
    const now = new Date();
    const will = new Date(now.getFullYear()+1, 0, 1).getTime();
    return (will - now.getTime()) / (1440 * 60 * 1000) | 0;
};

let r = getNextYearTime();
console.log(r, 'дна');
```

```js
const getNextYearTime=()=>{
    const now = new Date();
    const will = new Date(now.getFullYear()+1, 0, 1).getTime();
    return (will - now.getTime()) / (1440 * 60 * 1000) | 0;
};

let r = getNextYearTime();
console.log(r, 'дна');
```